# Error: Could not load file or assembly on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to run .NETCore Web App. I am using command
`sudo /usr/bin/dotnet /var/netcore/publish/App.dll`
where App.dll is Application.

I get an error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
> File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Any ideas?

Comment: The version do not match.  Easiest way of resolve is to use VS Solution Explorer.  Delete the reference and the add again.  The version will be updated in the csproj file with correct version.

Comment: Versions are the same (3.1.0.0) and I cannot find any direct reference in VS Solution Explorer

Comment: Somebody either manually put the dll into the bin folder or is is copied from the objects.  You can open the csproj with Notepad to see how it is getting copied and added to the project.